# button_click event from asp textbox only sending one number to sql stored procedure, why is my code not sending all characters?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, textbox

I have the below code-behind for an asp web page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TapeTrackingConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateContainerBySID", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // If you are passing any parameters to your Stored procedure 
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter_name", Parameter_value);
    //    int Session = int.Parse(DropDownList1.Text);
    //    int Container = int.Parse(ContainerID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContainerID", ContainerID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SessionID", DropDownList1.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

The @ContainerID shows all numbers input into the asp textbox, and a Response.Write shows all the characters.  However, when I check the database after the button click, it has only inserted the first number, not the whole number.  ie:  instead of 43263, it is inserting 4.

Here is the textbox and submit button code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ContainerID" MaxLength="10" runat="server" Columns="6" Rows="1" TextMode="Number"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" ></asp:Button>
```

I am a bit new to this, so I do appreciate the help!!!

Thanks!!
Jack

Comment: Maybe you declared `@ContainerID` as `varchar(1)` in the stored procedure?

Comment: post your procedure code body

Comment: It indeed was the varchar.  Being a bit new to SQL, I did not know that varchar without an explicit size defaults to 1, so my stored proc was chopping it down to 1 character.  Thank you to all who replied!